# VS2005 Web Deployment Project to VS2008 - ASPNET compiler errors

Tags: .net, asp.net, msbuild, wdproj

I'm having problems with a `wdproj` I've upgraded to VS2008; This is the error I'm getting while trying to compile the project using msbuild:

`ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The precompilation target directory
    (C:\code\CCI\CORUS\Website\Website_DeploymentProject\TempBuildDir\) cannot be in the same tree as the source application directory (C:\code\Website\).`

This is what the relevant section of my `wdproj` file looks like:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build;AfterBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.60403</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{36799864-6917-499B-814B-F542D3C6828B}</ProjectGuid>
    <SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\SWebSite</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
    <SourceWebProject>{283D5526-6B10-4CD1-B492-0283D351DC77}|WebSite\WebSite.csproj</SourceWebProject>
    <SourceWebVirtualPath>/WebSite</SourceWebVirtualPath>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildSourceCodePath)\WebSites\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
    <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
    <UseWebConfigReplacement>true</UseWebConfigReplacement>
    <ValidateWebConfigReplacement>true</ValidateWebConfigReplacement>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However that's mostly irrelavant as all I really need to do is somehow change / override the location of %(TempBuildDir) without manually hacking `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple - move the `.wdproj` file up a level, i.e. out of your Web Site Project and everything works fine.